# My website content is copied by SEO

Tags: seo, backlinks

I have noticed recently that my SEO executive is copying content from my website and posting it on different platforms and grabbing link to my website. I was wondering if Google will count my website content as duplicated?

The things he is doing like posting the same content on multiple blogs and social platforms and directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they will. It may even look like a [link scheme](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en) and attract a [penalty](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604824?hl=en).

I recommend you make sure he stops doing this, remove the duplicated content and links, and send him for some SEO training.

Comment: This. Fire your SEO if he's telling you this is a good idea. Duplicate content across domains isn't that likely to affect your main domain but it is a complete waste of time if that's how he's building links.

Comment: I say fire his ***! He did this without a plan that you signed off on?? Are you kidding me? He is very likely causing your site harm. Certainly he has at least gone rogue. Not what you need in an employee. Worse yet, he clearly has no idea of what he is doing.

Comment: closetnoc@I don't know how this type of guys get easily job, and myself not :p

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One thing still confusing is that what if people start doing it for competitors websites. Like copying their content and publish that on different blogs and creating links to their website.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can always put a canonical tag on your original website. You should always rewrite the content you want to use once more.